# Add Google Ads code

Tags: magento-1.9, html

I would like to add this Google add code

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- www.duajempol.com -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6695083499962649"
     data-ad-slot="2640118019"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

In which html file should I add it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add it in any file. you can simply use the System->Configuration->Design->HTML Head->Miscellaneous Scripts section in the config and add your code int here. It will be visible in all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your **header.phtml** file, it's located on the following

/`MagentoROOTDIR/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html`

Added the following code at top of the file.

**Alternately,**  you can add from you admin panel,  see the following

[Google Analytics with Magento](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_google_analytics.htm)